# Using macros for function without parameters

Tags: c++, struct, macros, getter

I have a struct namely TStream. It have 2 protected members which are accessed with there getters.

```
struct TStream {
protected:
    long long size, position;
    FILE *f;
public:
    ...
    long long Get_Size(void) {
        return size;
    }

    long long Get_Pos(void) {
        return position;
    }
} TStream;
```

Can I replace use of Get_Size() and Get_Pos() with macros?

```
#define Size Get_Size()
#define Position Get_Pos()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159924/discussion-on-question-by-mian-bilawal-using-macros-for-function-without-paramet).

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want here is a class with `private` data members and `protected` setter functions and `public` getters:

```
class TStream {
    long long size, position;
    FILE *f;
protected:
    void Set_Size(long long value) {
        size = value;
    }
    void Set_Pos(long long value) {
        position = value;
    }
public:
    // ...
    long long Get_Size(void) const {
        return size;
    }

    long long Get_Pos(void) const {
        return position;
    }
};
```

Such only classes/structs directly inheriting from `TStream` can change the `private` members, but the values are still accessible from `public` scope.

Macros won't change anything about these c++ scoping aspects anyways.